# "ld returned 1 exit status" and "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' "

Tags: c

I was bored, so I started to study something new, in this case, C.

I was trying to do a basic script in c but I'm having this error, and i don't know what is wrong.

```
//Tablas

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double i, j, p;
    int x, y;

    printf ("Tablas del: ");
    scanf ("%i", &x);
    printf ("Hasta el: ");
    scanf ("%i", &y);

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Tablas.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("No se ha podido abrir/crear/reemplazar el archivo\n\a");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("Espere mientras se calcula los resulatdos.\n");
    system ("del tablas.txt");

    for (i = x ; i <= y ; i++) {
        for (j = x ; j <= 10 ; j++) {
            fprinf(f, "%f x %f = %f\n", i, j, i*j);
        }
    }
    printf ("\nFin\n\a");
    system ("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: delete this(`system ("del tablas.txt");`) line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `#include <stdlib.h>` for `exit` to work.

Comment: Yeah, that fix one thing, but still giving me the ld returned 1 exit status error

Comment: ok, so there's another error, your `fprinf` should really be `fprintf` - pay attention to the details